# Could not initialize class com.linuxnet.jpcsc.PCSC in JCManager

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader

My **ACS ACR38** reader works properly via it's **SDK** and **GPJ** but it's look like that **JCManager** can't access to it. This is output of JCManagr when I open it :

[image]

This is the error message :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.linuxnet.jpcsc.PCSC
    at com.braicu.jcm.card.CardWorker.disconnectCard(CardWorker.java:507)
    at com.braicu.jcm.JCManager$22.construct(JCManager.java:619)
    at com.braicu.jcm.layout.MySwingWorker$2.run(MySwingWorker.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

I downloaded **jpcsc.dll** and copied it in this directories :

1. C:\Windows\
2. C:\Windows\System
3. C:\Windows\System32
4. **D:\jcManager\res**

D:\Java Card\jcManager\res

But when I try to register these files with `regsvr32` command in the **Command-Prompt**
I receive this error :
[image]

I restart my system, and problem didn't solve yet.

**Q: How can I handle this problem?**

I appreciate your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2):

`jpcsc` is a very old library that does not seem to be maintained anymore. The last time I took a look at its structure and code I was actually rather horrified.

It looks however that somebody took notice and rewrote the tool to use `javax.smartcardio`. This much newer PCSC interface took quite a few hints from the older `jpcsc` and did a much better job at it.

You can find the source [on github](https://github.com/martinpaljak/jcManager). I would recommend you upgrade to that version.

Comment: Thank you MR.Owlstead. but it works fine on my pc! the error is only for my laptop! btw, I upgrade it with the link that you recommecd and nothing changed!

Comment: For upgrade I download it and paste it's content in the old one that I used before. is this right?

Comment: Don't you think the .dll would want one?

Comment: Oh sorry! in device manager? yes there is! but with an Exclamation point in a yellow triangle on it! it's driver not installed properly ! but how it works fine in gpj and its SDK?

Comment: Maybe it has direct support for the reader, instead of going through the Windows PCSC layer.

Comment: what about the **GPJ**. It has direct support too?!

Comment: Don't really know about that. Could also be a different Java version, some versions don't have smartcardio support (i.e. older 64 bit versions).

Comment: In my PC, I installed a 32-bit Windows-7, but in my laptop I have a 64-bit Windows 7. could it be origin of the error?

Comment: Yes, but I guess it remains debugging from a distance - without the PC it is guesswork :(

Comment: OK, Thank you dear MR. Owlstead. I'll try to solve it and I'll keep you informed :)